# Can I format n numbers in Python

Tags: python-3.x

How can I print all numbers in a given range to given number of columns, where every colums is of width 6 character and there is a space between colums? I tried to use format:

```
for i in range(0,nolines):
    for j in range(0,nocolums):
         print("{0:6}{1:6}".format(number1,number2))
```

but found that this approach won't work as I need more general code to format n, where n is given by user input, numbers instead of two. So can I print n numbers by using format?

For example, if input is

```
min = 20, max = 104, numbers on one line = 10
```

the program should print

```
   20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29 
   30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39 
   40    41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49 
   50    51    52    53    54    55    56    57    58    59 
   60    61    62    63    64    65    66    67    68    69 
   70    71    72    73    74    75    76    77    78    79 
   80    81    82    83    84    85    86    87    88    89 
   90    91    92    93    94    95    96    97    98    99 
  100   101   102   103   104
```

Comment: pls give some sample input and expect output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def print_range(start, stop, ncolumns, width=6):
    for i in range(start, stop, ncolumns):
        print(' '.join(['{:{}d}'.format(j, width)
                        for j in range(i, min(i + ncolumns, stop))]))
```

Example:

```
>>> print_range(20, 105, ncolumns=10)
    20     21     22     23     24     25     26     27     28     29
    30     31     32     33     34     35     36     37     38     39
    40     41     42     43     44     45     46     47     48     49
    50     51     52     53     54     55     56     57     58     59
    60     61     62     63     64     65     66     67     68     69
    70     71     72     73     74     75     76     77     78     79
    80     81     82     83     84     85     86     87     88     89
    90     91     92     93     94     95     96     97     98     99
   100    101    102    103    104
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `str.rjust` method:

```
lines = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [111, 222, 333],
]

for line in lines:
    for n in line:
        print(str(n).rjust(6), end='')

    print()
```